# MySql Throwing back errors after Upgrading WAMP SERVER

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE popped = '0' ORDER BY id DESC) t WHERE t.userTo = '".$myId."' GROUP BY t.noteId, t.dataId, t.type
```

This code above runs perfectly on my Wamp server which was running on MYSQL5.5.8. Then I upgraded to the latest Wamp v3.0.6 which is running on MYSQL5.7.14 and I begin to get the #1055 error.

So finally, I came up with this code in the image below[image: SQL Query]

But I get this error[image: Error thrown back]

I have totally tried all I can but can't fix this error. Can Someone help me out with this?

And I really need the sub-query

Comment: What is the PHP version and PHP code you are using to execute the query?

Comment: It's PHP5.6.25.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because it's a workaround, not a solution. My default solution for this is to update my MySQL config to set the `sql_mode` to one that does not contain `only_full_group_by`. I'd be interested to find out what the proper solution is, though.

Comment: @rickdenhaan okay. But how do I do this, can u give me a clue?

Comment: Added an answer for how to do that, I hope someone else can add an answer on how to make your query compatible with the `only_full_group_by` mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **workaround** to make MySQL 5.7 act like your previous version for `GROUP BY` queries -- ***this should NOT be the accepted answer***:

First, find out your current `sql_mode`:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

On my test server, this returned:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

The error you're seeing is caused by the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` flag. You can update your MySQL configuration file to remove that flag. Find and edit your `my.cnf` file (IIRC you can access it from the WAMP menu in the taskbar icon, but it's been a few years since I last used WAMP so that might have changed).

Check if there's already a `sql_mode` defined in there. If not, add it somewhere under the `[mysqld]` heading. Make its value the same as whatever `sql_mode` you got from the previous query, *minus* the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` flag. So in my case, that would be:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Save the file and restart MySQL to load the changes.

Note that changes made to the `my.cnf` file will most likely be overwritten the next time you update WAMP, so this is not a permanent solution. For a permanent fix, you should update your queries to be compatible with the default `sql_mode`.